# Akka remote : trying to connect two machines

Tags: scala, akka, akka-cluster

I have two physical different machines (192.168.1.37 and 192.168.1.99), I can ping easily each machine from the other one.
I'm trying to connect them with Akka remote (I'm using Java)

My local machine (trying to send a message to an actor on the remote one) :

```
akka {
  actor {
    provider = remote
  }
  
  remote {
    artery {
      enabled = on
      transport = tcp
      canonical.hostname = "192.168.1.37"
      canonical.port = 2556
    }
  }
}
```

And the code :

```
ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("local", ConfigFactory.load("akka.conf"));
ActorSelection selection = system.actorSelection("akka://remote@192.168.1.99:2555/user/actor");
selection.tell("trying to connect...", ActorRef.noSender());
```

Now the config for my remote machine (I started it before launching local one) :

```
akka {
  actor {
    provider = remote
  }
  
  remote {
    artery {
      enabled = on
      transport = tcp
      canonical.hostname = "192.168.1.99"
      canonical.port = 2555
    }
  }
}
```

And the code :

```
ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("remote", ConfigFactory.load("akka.conf"));
ActorRef actor = system.actorOf(Props.create(SimpleActor.class),"actor");
```

Then I run the remote JVM and start the local one after. Here are the logs I got for the local one :

```
[INFO] [07/06/2020 19:42:06.950] [main] [akka.remote.artery.tcp.ArteryTcpTransport(akka://local)] Remoting started with transport [Artery tcp]; listening on address [akka://local@192.168.1.37:2556] with UID [-6291059934924481437]
[WARN] [07/06/2020 19:42:12.653] [local-akka.remote.default-remote-dispatcher-7] [akka.stream.Log(akka://local/system/StreamSupervisor-0)] [outbound connection to [akka://remote@192.168.1.99:2555], message stream] Upstream failed, cause: StreamTcpException: Tcp command [Connect(192.168.1.99/<unresolved>:2555,None,List(),Some(5000 milliseconds),true)] failed because of akka.io.TcpOutgoingConnection$$anon$2: Connect timeout of Some(5000 milliseconds) expired
[WARN] [07/06/2020 19:42:12.653] [local-akka.remote.default-remote-dispatcher-4] [akka.stream.Log(akka://local/system/StreamSupervisor-0)] [outbound connection to [akka://remote@192.168.1.99:2555], control stream] Upstream failed, cause: StreamTcpException: Tcp command [Connect(192.168.1.99/<unresolved>:2555,None,List(),Some(5000 milliseconds),true)] failed because of akka.io.TcpOutgoingConnection$$anon$2: Connect timeout of Some(5000 milliseconds) expired
[WARN] [07/06/2020 19:42:12.655] [local-akka.remote.default-remote-dispatcher-4] [RestartWithBackoffFlow(akka://local)] Restarting graph due to failure. stack_trace:  (akka.stream.StreamTcpException: Tcp command [Connect(192.168.1.99/<unresolved>:2555,None,List(),Some(5000 milliseconds),true)] failed because of akka.io.TcpOutgoingConnection$$anon$2: Connect timeout of Some(5000 milliseconds) expired)
[WARN] [07/06/2020 19:42:12.655] [local-akka.remote.default-remote-dispatcher-7] [RestartWithBackoffFlow(akka://local)] Restarting graph due to failure. stack_trace:  (akka.stream.StreamTcpException: Tcp command [Connect(192.168.1.99/<unresolved>:2555,None,List(),Some(5000 milliseconds),true)] failed because of akka.io.TcpOutgoingConnection$$anon$2: Connect timeout of Some(5000 milliseconds) expired)
[WARN] [07/06/2020 19:42:19.349] [local-akka.remote.default-remote-dispatcher-7] [akka.stream.Log(akka://local/system/StreamSupervisor-0)] [outbound connection to [akka://remote@192.168.1.99:2555], message stream] Upstream failed, cause: StreamTcpException: Tcp command [Connect(192.168.1.99/<unresolved>:2555,None,List(),Some(5000 milliseconds),true)] failed because of akka.io.TcpOutgoingConnection$$anon$2: Connect timeout of Some(5000 milliseconds) expired
[WARN] [07/06/2020 19:42:19.350] [local-akka.remote.default-remote-dispatcher-7] [RestartWithBackoffFlow(akka://local)] Restarting graph due to failure. stack_trace:  (akka.stream.StreamTcpException: Tcp command [Connect(192.168.1.99/<unresolved>:2555,None,List(),Some(5000 milliseconds),true)] failed because of akka.io.TcpOutgoingConnection$$anon$2: Connect timeout of Some(5000 milliseconds) expired)
[WARN] [07/06/2020 19:42:20.346] [local-akka.remote.default-remote-dispatcher-7] [akka.stream.Log(akka://local/system/StreamSupervisor-0)] [outbound connection to [akka://remote@192.168.1.99:2555], control stream] Upstream failed, cause: StreamTcpException: Tcp command [Connect(192.168.1.99/<unresolved>:2555,None,List(),Some(5000 milliseconds),true)] failed because of akka.io.TcpOutgoingConnection$$anon$2: Connect timeout of Some(5000 milliseconds) expired
[WARN] [07/06/2020 19:42:20.346] [local-akka.remote.default-remote-dispatcher-7] [RestartWithBackoffFlow(akka://local)] Restarting graph due to failure. stack_trace:  (akka.stream.StreamTcpException: Tcp command [Connect(192.168.1.99/<unresolved>:2555,None,List(),Some(5000 milliseconds),true)] failed because of akka.io.TcpOutgoingConnection$$anon$2: Connect timeout of Some(5000 milliseconds) expired)
[WARN] [07/06/2020 19:42:26.365] [local-akka.remote.default-remote-dispatcher-4] [akka.stream.Log(akka://local/system/StreamSupervisor-0)] [outbound connection to [akka://remote@192.168.1.99:2555], message stream] Upstream failed, cause: StreamTcpException: Tcp command [Connect(192.168.1.99/<unresolved>:2555,None,List(),Some(5000 milliseconds),true)] failed because of akka.io.TcpOutgoingConnection$$anon$2: Connect timeout of Some(5000 milliseconds) expired
[WARN] [07/06/2020 19:42:26.366] [local-akka.remote.default-remote-dispatcher-4] [RestartWithBackoffFlow(akka://local)] Restarting graph due to failure. stack_trace:  (akka.stream.StreamTcpException: Tcp command [Connect(192.168.1.99/<unresolved>:2555,None,List(),Some(5000 milliseconds),true)] failed because of akka.io.TcpOutgoingConnection$$anon$2: Connect timeout of Some(5000 milliseconds) expired)
[WARN] [07/06/2020 19:42:27.331] [local-akka.remote.default-remote-dispatcher-7] [akka.stream.Log(akka://local/system/StreamSupervisor-0)] [outbound connection to [akka://remote@192.168.1.99:2555], control stream] Upstream failed, cause: OutboundHandshake$HandshakeTimeoutException: Handshake with [akka://remote@192.168.1.99:2555] did not complete within 20000 ms
[INFO] [07/06/2020 19:42:27.335] [local-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-3] [akka://local/deadLetters] Message [java.lang.String] without sender to Actor[akka://local/deadLetters] was not delivered. [1] dead letters encountered. If this is not an expected behavior, then [Actor[akka://local/deadLetters]] may have terminated unexpectedly, This logging can be turned off or adjusted with configuration settings 'akka.log-dead-letters' and 'akka.log-dead-letters-during-shutdown'.
[ERROR] [07/06/2020 19:42:27.342] [local-akka.remote.default-remote-dispatcher-7] [akka.remote.artery.Association(akka://local)] Outbound message stream to [akka://remote@192.168.1.99:2555] failed. Restarting it. Handshake with [akka://remote@192.168.1.99:2555] did not complete within 20000 ms (akka.remote.artery.OutboundHandshake$HandshakeTimeoutException: Handshake with [akka://remote@192.168.1.99:2555] did not complete within 20000 ms)
[ERROR] [07/06/2020 19:42:27.348] [local-akka.remote.default-remote-dispatcher-7] [akka.remote.artery.Association(akka://local)] Outbound control stream to [akka://remote@192.168.1.99:2555] failed. Restarting it. Handshake with [akka://remote@192.168.1.99:2555] did not complete within 20000 ms (akka.remote.artery.OutboundHandshake$HandshakeTimeoutException: Handshake with [akka://remote@192.168.1.99:2555] did not complete within 20000 ms)
```

Comment: I would recommend using akka-cluster, or creating an akka-http or akka-grpc service on your service node, for other services to communicate with, rather than using akka remoting itself.  Classic akka remoting has been deprecated.  See the advice at the top of this page in the docs. https://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/remoting-artery.html

Answer (score 2):

Your example looks fine. I have one that does the same thing for 2 JVM but in the same machine. The first thing thaat I recommend is to test everything in only one machine but different JVMs. If it works then you got to 2 machines. Here I suggest to check the ports first because pinging does not uses TCP. Check this question:
https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/37897/72199

The standard ping command does not use TCP or UDP. It uses ICMP. To be more precise ICMP type 8 (echo message) and type 0 (echo reply message) are used. ICMP has no ports!

See RFC792 for further details.

My suggestion is that you can test the specific port using telnet:

Open a command prompt
Type in "telnet  " on each machine
For example, we would type “telnet 192.168.1.99 2555" from 192.168.1.37 and vice versa.
If a blank screen appears then the port is open, and the test is successful.
If you receive a connecting... message or an error message then something is blocking that port.

Besides that, using akka cluster is easier...